# Labview: Client can not connect to OPC UA server

Tags: labview, opc-ua

I am trying to connect OPC UA client to an OPC UA server over the ethernet cable. I receive the following error

---

**LabVIEW:  (Hex 0xFFFA8EF7) The OPC UA client cannot connect to the OPC UA server because the security policy, username, or password is invalid.**

client can connect anonymously so I dont need to add user/pass but when I add this the error changes to

---

**LabVIEW:  (Hex 0xFFFA8ED3) The status of the OPC UA server is uncertain**

so I am not sure where is the problem?? any help will be useful

Answer (score 0):

With LabVIEW DSC versions 2011 and previous you would see the Hex 0xFFFA8ED3 error returned from the server whenever it did not trust the client connection. This error output was changed in later versions. If you're using 2011 or previous I would confirm that you are correctly pointing to the trusted server certificate on the client side. As stated in the [help](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371618J-01/lvmve/establishing_connection_btwn_opcua_svr_clnt/),

> The trusted server certificates control of the Connect VI specifies
>   the file paths of the certificates that the OPC UA client trusts. You
>   must manually copy the trusted server certificates from the OPC UA
>   server machine to the OPC UA client machine, and then enter the path
>   to the trusted server certificates control of the OPC UA client.

Refer to the [Creating an OPC UA Server Application and an OPC UA Client Application](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371618J-01/lvmve/creating_opcua_svr_opcua_clnt/) in the DSC Module help for more information and a general tutorial.

Comment: I am using 2014 version. I have added trusted server certificate by giving path to the copy and it seems to be correct if I remove the certificate, it gives error "The certificate provided by OPC UA server is not valid...".so I think my certificate is valid. But the problem seems to be something else.

Comment: Even If I enter the wrong password the error is uncertain server.The server is on PLC and client should connect anonymously. If I remove the user/pass string from client block-dig the error becomes the first one (Hex 0xFFFA8EF7). I have gone through the given link already its been very useful. Unfortunately I am new to labview so I am facing difficulty in connecting client to server

Comment: Is there a possibility that server might not be correctly configured? Server is on a PLC and the PLC operator just turn it on. He says that he cannot change any properties on server.

Comment: Possibly, yes. Much of the instructions provided in the NI help assume that you are using Client and Server code defined in LabVIEW code. I would provide more detail in your original post about which PLC you're using and what connection requirements it has for OPC clients. Also, test out whether or not you can connect to the server from a different client other than LabVIEW. Do those work properly?

Comment: Also, I have a suspicion that we may be running to problems with DCOM settings. This isn't something I have played around with much before but there is a fair bit of documentation about it. Check out this guide for example: https://www.kepware.com/support/resource-library/connectivity-guides/opc-ua.pdf

Comment: I am not sure how but somehow it is working now.I have also gone through above links it is very useful for OPC Ua. Thanks for your help.